# Call to undefined function error even function is defined

Tags: php, runtime-error

I have a file which is session secured "admin.php". This is default page after login.
This throwing an error given below:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function listPages() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cd-website\cms\admin.php on line 14

```
<?php
/*
* initialize session for admin
*/
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['admin_user']))
{
    require_once '../cms/config.php';

    $action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : '';

    if ($action == null)
    {
        listPages();
        exit;
    }

    /*
     * using switch for choosing function
     */
    switch($action)
    {
        case 'ManagePages':
            ManagePages();
            break;
        case 'listUsers':
            listUsers();
            break;
        case 'orderList':
            listOrders();
            break;
        case 'listBanner':
            listBanners();
            break;
        case 'NewsletterUser':
            NewsletterUsers();
            break;
        case 'Newsletter':
            Newsletter();
            break;
        case 'listQuestion':
            listquestions();
            break;
        case 'testinomial':
            listTesti();
            break;
        default:
            listPages();
    }

    /*
     * different function for different tasks
     */
    function ManagePages()
    {
        listPages();
    }

    function listUsers()
    {
        // include listusers.php here. required rows is in listusers.php file
    }

    function listOrders()
    {
        // include listorders.php here
    }

    function  listBanners()
    {
        // include listbanners.php here
    }

    function  NewsletterUsers()
    {
        // include listNUsers.php here
    }

    function listquestions()
    {
        // include listquestions.php here.
    }

    function listTesti()
    {
        // include listTesti.php here.
    }

    function Newsletter()
    {
        //  include newsletter.php
    }

    function listPages()
    {
        //  include listPages.php here
    }
}
else
{
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

When i try to solve error on line 14, it shows error on every line where `listPages()` exist.

Why it so? Please help!

Comment: doesn;t seem any error though its very complex way of coding

Comment: no error found  ; see [working demo with minimal setting](http://codepad.viper-7.com/abxLmp)

Comment: @diEcho if there were no error in the code why i will post here. I am not mad and not the other people who are responding. Think a bit before writing anything.

Comment: i am not saying that you posted wrong. I said that i have tried on my end and it seems perfect. You can see the link i have given. Just chill Dhondu.

Comment: @diEcho hahaha... nice word invented Dhondu!

Answer (score 10):

You declared a function inside a `if` block, which can be tricky. According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php, [conditional functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php#example-147), they will not be available until the execution reaches the function definition, but if you place the function outside, the sequence doesn't matter and the function is available throughout the whole script.

```
<?php
bar(); // OK
function bar()
{
  echo "I exist immediately upon program start.\n";
}

if (TRUE) {
  foo(); // Fails because `foo` isn't defined yet.
  function foo()
  {
    echo "I don't exist until program execution reaches me.\n";
  }
}
```

And please check http://codepad.org/EMW3kzqC.

So the solution is to declare the function outside the `if` block, or place them above the location where you use it (if it really needs to reside inside the `if` block).

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. I were also thinking same.

Comment: no, its not right. PHP parse the complete file not in chunked  way like JS

Comment: but that `if` condition is regarding session variable. it session available doesn't exit , that whole code of block will not execute.

Comment: assume we are inside first `if` block then how can u say that `listpages()` will not run,

Comment: there may be some other error. here you can see the working demo : http://codepad.viper-7.com/abxLmp

Comment: Thanks Alvin for explaination! This will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

here two solutions are ther one is using the Class, above method
 if you are using the above method the function should be defined before calling that function.

so

```
function listPages()
   {
                              //include listPages.php here
   }

after that call listPages()
```

Comment: Hmmm....it working but i have a same type of code which works fine. why it so. By the way thanks Naveen!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exceptionally familiar with php, but it looks like you're defining your functions only within the big if block there. You might be running into the way php handles scope.

Try placing your function definitions outside of the if block and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Check if Your function is set before calling. In PHP You have to declare functions before calling them.

Your error tells clearly that when You call `listPages()` this function doesn't exists yet.

I'm sure if You place just after:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['admin_user']))
{
```

Declaration of this function

```
function listPages()
{
    //Do something here
}
```

Your error will disapear.

What i can see You are trying to use functions in structural code as they would be in some class (object oriented code) and unfortunetly PHP dosen't work that way.

Comment: No, in PHP, you don't have to declare functions before calling them. This is misinformation. PHP is not Python !!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
/*
* initialize session for admin
*/
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['admin_user']))
{
    require_once '../cms/config.php';

    $action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : '';

    if ($action == null)
    {
        listPages();
        exit;
    }


    /*Functions */
    function ManagePages()
    {
        listPages();
    }

    function listUsers()
    {
        // include listusers.php here. required rows is in listusers.php file
    }

    function listOrders()
    {
        // include listorders.php here
    }

    function  listBanners()
    {
        // include listbanners.php here
    }

    function  NewsletterUsers()
    {
        // include listNUsers.php here
    }

    function listquestions()
    {
        // include listquestions.php here.
    }

    function listTesti()
    {
        // include listTesti.php here.
    }

    function Newsletter()
    {
        //  include newsletter.php
    }

    function listPages()
    {
        //  include listPages.php here
    }


    /*
     * using switch for choosing function
     */
    switch($action)
    {
        case 'ManagePages':
            ManagePages();
            break;
        case 'listUsers':
            listUsers();
            break;
        case 'orderList':
            listOrders();
            break;
        case 'listBanner':
            listBanners();
            break;
        case 'NewsletterUser':
            NewsletterUsers();
            break;
        case 'Newsletter':
            Newsletter();
            break;
        case 'listQuestion':
            listquestions();
            break;
        case 'testinomial':
            listTesti();
            break;
        default:
            listPages();
    }

    /*
     * different function for different tasks
     */

}
else
{
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

Comment: For future reference, if you answer a question, please include an explanation as to what you have changed in the code provided. Otherwise, how do we know what you have corrected and changed?